# Petapoco - Extending the T4 template generated poco objects

Tags: petapoco

For a new project I started using PetaPoco T4 template with `GenerateOperations`, `GeneratePocos`, and `GenerateCommon` all = true.

However, I want to customize the poco object generated. If I modify the class generated it will be wiped out every time I modify the schema. What's the best way to extend the generated poco objects?

---

As Schotime said, I think the solution might be using partial class but I am having a hard time to get that working. 
Here is my code structure.

in Database.cs file (autogenerated by T4 template)

```
namespace PetaPocoNISEntities
{
    public partial class PetaPocoNISEntities : Database
    {

        [TableName("GivenQuestion")]
        [PrimaryKey("Id")]
        [ExplicitColumns]    
        public partial class GivenQuestion : PetaPocoNISEntities.Record<GivenQuestion>  
        {
            [Column] 
            public int Id             
            { 
                ....
            }
        }
}
```

}

so I created the following partial classes.

```
namespace PetaPocoNISEntities
{
    public partial class PetaPocoNISEntities : Database
    {
        public partial class GivenQuestion : PetaPocoNISEntities.Record<GivenQuestion>

            [ResultColumn]
            public QuestionRepository QuestionRepository { get; set; }

            [ResultColumn]
            public List<GivenAnswer> GivenAnswers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used the same name space.

but then when I tried to use the class, the following code complains that the gq (which is GivenQuestion) doesn not contain the QuestinoRepository method?

```
var givenAnswers = results.Where(gq => gq.QuestionRepository .QuestionCode.Trim().ToUpper() == _formData.Trim().ToUpper());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `partial` classes.
Then you could modify the partial class to add extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should not be nested as you have them written.  I've had no trouble extending my POCO objects with partial classes.

Also, I'd decorate the added columns with [PetaPoco.Ignore] as in:

```
public partial class GivenQuestion
{
    [PetaPoco.Ignore]
    public QuestionRepository QuestionRepository { get; set; }
    [PetaPoco.Ignore]
    public List<GivenAnswer> GivenAnswers { get; set; }
}
```